Forming a question over an indirect object
If a question sentence is formed by replacing an indirect object with a question word, should the preposition “to” be used?
Source sentence:

I gave you a cookie.

Interrogative sentence:

Whom did I give a cookie?

or

Whom did I give a cookie to?

or

To whom did I give a cookie?

Related: “Relative pronoun ‘whom’ used as an indirect object of a verb with two objects.”

Most native speakers have given up using whom in most if not all contexts. The notable exception is when it's preceded by the preposition to. So you'll still hear To whom am I speaking? from time to time (formal usage on the telephone at work), but Whom am I speaking to? isn't likely. Mostly it's just Who am I speaking to? today (To who am I speaking? sounds a little bit clunky to me). So for your specific example, none of your suggestions are likely. It's Who did I give a cookie to?

"Whom did I give a cookie?" is just plain wrong. It's incomplete and would never be said by a native speaker. "Whom did I give a cookie to?" and "To whom did I give a cookie?" are both acceptable if rather formal or clunky sounding. As FumbleFingers says "Who did I give a cookie to?" is the most common usage. Note that "To whom did I give a cookie?" is an attempt to apply the fictitious rule "Never end a sentence with a preposition" made up in the 19th century to make English more like Latin!

Be careful when you use "who" or "whom" in an examination. You cannot always replace "whom" with "who". Whom
is the object form of who. We use whom to refer to people in formal styles or in writing, when the person is the object of the verb

@JamesMathai, do you mean the direct object or the indirect object?

Answer:
to give a cookie to someone OR to give someone a cookie
Question: To whom did I give a cookie?= very correct, yes.
BUT in regular, contemporary speech we actually say:
Who did I give a cookie to?
If you use "to whom", you don't repeat the to. If you use who as a subject, the to goes at the end.
You can say: I gave you a cookie OR I gave a cookie to you. BUT the question form requires the "to" at the end with who at the beginning or the beginning with to whom. It's true we tend to not use whom as much in modern speech.
That said, personally, I would likely use it in sentences such as: Whom did you see in the garage? [I saw him in the garage.]
